# What's wrong with this shader code, it crashes on the mobile device on the last line of the fragment shader?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, shader

I got this shader from the unity asset store, it is simulating some "force field" effect, it runs OK on PC, but crashes on my android device. The issue generally occurs on the last lines of the fragment shader code:

```
...    
...
fixed3 final = outterMask * _OuterTint.a//outterMask is a fixed3 and
                                        //_OuterTint is a fixed4
return fixed4(final,1.0);
```

I did some inspecting, and if I replace the last line into

```
return fixed4(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
```

it no longer crashes on the mobile device. Also, if I replace the second to last line into

```
fixed3 final = _OuterTint.a;
```

it would also work OK.

So it seems like returning the calculated `final` value caused the crash, while all the code above didn't, now I just don't understand what kind of value would be wrong.

**By returning what kind of value from the fragment shader could cause a crash on the device?** I need to know this to do further inspection, i tried to simply clamp and saturate this value, but it crashed anyway.

Full fragment shader code:

```
/// FRAGMENT
                fixed4 frag (v2f i) : COLOR
                {   
                    int interpolators = 24;
                    fixed4 pos[24]; 
                    fixed power[24];            

                    fixed3 innerMask = 0.0; 
                    fixed3 outterMask = 0.0;

                    pos[0] = _Pos_0;
                    pos[1] = _Pos_1;
                    pos[2] = _Pos_2;
                    pos[3] = _Pos_3;
                    pos[4] = _Pos_4;
                    pos[5] = _Pos_5;
                    pos[6] = _Pos_6;
                    pos[7] = _Pos_7;
                    pos[8] = _Pos_8;
                    pos[9] = _Pos_9;
                    pos[10] = _Pos_10;
                    pos[11] = _Pos_11;
                    pos[12] = _Pos_12;
                    pos[13] = _Pos_13;
                    pos[14] = _Pos_14;
                    pos[15] = _Pos_15;
                    pos[16] = _Pos_16;
                    pos[17] = _Pos_17;
                    pos[18] = _Pos_18;
                    pos[19] = _Pos_19;
                    pos[20] = _Pos_20;
                    pos[21] = _Pos_21;
                    pos[22] = _Pos_22;
                    pos[23] = _Pos_23;

                    power[0] = _Pow_0;
                    power[1] = _Pow_1;
                    power[2] = _Pow_2;
                    power[3] = _Pow_3;
                    power[4] = _Pow_4;
                    power[5] = _Pow_5;
                    power[6] = _Pow_6;
                    power[7] = _Pow_7;
                    power[8] = _Pow_8;
                    power[9] = _Pow_9;
                    power[10] = _Pow_10;
                    power[11] = _Pow_11;
                    power[12] = _Pow_12;
                    power[13] = _Pow_13;
                    power[14] = _Pow_14;
                    power[15] = _Pow_15;
                    power[16] = _Pow_16;
                    power[17] = _Pow_17;
                    power[18] = _Pow_18;
                    power[19] = _Pow_19;
                    power[20] = _Pow_20;
                    power[21] = _Pow_21;
                    power[22] = _Pow_22;
                    power[23] = _Pow_23;


                    for(int x = 0; x < interpolators; x++)
                    {
                        fixed dist = distance(pos[x].xyz + i.normal * _Offset, i.oPos.xyz);

                        innerMask += pow(saturate(1 - dist * ((power[x] + _InnterOffset) + (1 - pos[x].w) * 2)), _InnerPow) * pos[x].w;
                        outterMask += pow(saturate(1 - dist * (_OutterOffset - (1 - pos[x].w) * 2)), _OutterPow) * pos[x].w;
                    }

                    fixed field_Tex = pow(tex2D(_FieldTex, uvPanner(i.uv, _FieldPanSpeed, _FieldPanSpeed)), 2.2).r;
                    fixed field_Tex_inv = pow(tex2D(_FieldTex, uvPanner(i.uv, -_FieldPanSpeed, -_FieldPanSpeed)), 2.2).r;


                    fixed3 fieldColor = lerp(_OuterTint, _InnerTint, field_Tex.r).rgb;
                    fixed sparksMask = saturate(field_Tex * field_Tex_inv).x;
                    fixed3 sparks = saturate(sparksMask * fieldColor) * _FieldSparks;       

                    outterMask = saturate(outterMask * _OuterTint.rgb);
                    innerMask = saturate(innerMask * _InnerTint.rgb);

                    fixed3 final = outterMask * _OuterTint.a * 10 + innerMask * _InnerTint.a * 10;
                    final += field_Tex * fieldColor * outterMask * _FieldBG;
                    final += sparks * outterMask * 10;

                    return fixed4(final, 1.0);
                }
```

Comment: Please add more code to support your question.

Comment: thanks for replying, i attached the full frag shader code to the post, yet like i indicated in the first post, i think what i'm missing is probably something outside the general code itself but indicated by the last a few lines

Comment: Have you tried getting the results of your calculations in the console by help of System.out.println() method ?

Comment: well since we're on GPU here, i can only output the values as colors, yet the output i saw didn't make any sense...  but at last i had tried out which lines of code were causing the crash, if i reduce the loop count "for(int x = 0; x < interpolators; x++)" a little bit, like to 3 loops, it stopped crashing, haven't gotten to the bottom of it but my problem is solved as i don't really need that many loops there.

Answer (score 0):

I finally worked out which line of code is causing the program to crash, it's 
when the "for(int x = 0; x < interpolators; x++)" loop count is bigger(24 in my case), when i reduce the counter to around 3, it no longer crashed, and this solved my problem as i need actually just 1 loop for my app.